# How read keys in JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

How **read dynamic keys** in JSON , **NodeJs** and or **JQuery** and or **JavaScript**?

I did not find. **I did try.**

Need find out name  keys, and read values.

**Keys dynamic**

```
{
  "marka1": {
    "name": "Mika",
  },
  "beti1": {
    "name": "Yii",
  }
}
```

Comment: Object.keys(obj) gives a list of the keys of obj.

Comment: wow...how hard is it to search `javascript object keys`??

Comment: @charlietfl I did not find. I did try

Comment: @Yottatron How read field 'name' ?

Comment: @FiR what are you doing with those edits ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Need find out name keys, and read values.

```
var obj = {
  "marka1": {
    "name": "Mika",
  },
  "beti1": {
    "name": "Yii",
  }
};
```

you can get the keys inside this object by

```
var keys = Object.keys( obj);
console.log(keys);
```

now you can iterate this `keys` array to get values of each property.

Comment: How read field 'name' ?   I try |||   var obj = JSON.parse(obj);  var keys = Object.keys(obj);  obj.keys[0].name  |||   but give errors

Answer (score 0):

The "key" should be a property of the object and not the name of the object. The data structure should look more like :

[
 {
    key : "marka1",
    name : "Mika"
 }
]

With it being an array of objects, this will allow you to reference the key of each object.

If the data is formatted like that, use Object.keys() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys to grab the key

Comment: what's wrong with object shown? This doesn't answer problem of unknown key names and there are lots of use cases for dynamically generating unknown object key names

Comment: @charlietfl updated answer

Comment: Object.keys() - good worked!) Ty)